# Why are no pagination links displaying in this WordPress template?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm having trouble understanding or even diagnosing why pagination is not being displayed in my home.php file that I've created in my twentyseventeen-child theme. I have 3 blog posts, and I want only one to display, with pagination at the bottom.

I'm running WordPress 4.7.2, and according to [this](https://digwp.com/2016/10/wordpress-post-navigation-redux/) article I should be using the_posts_pagination() to display pagination for my posts, but nothing is appearing. I've setup a custom query as described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query) (passing params as an array instead of query string):

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

There are 3 posts, and if I set the query to this then I see all three on my home.php page:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

When I set 'posts_per_page' to 1, and then call the_posts_pagination(), I only see the first post, and no pagination. I don't understand why no pagination is appearing, as there ARE more pages to display. I'm still really new at WordPress though, so I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious.

Here is my complete code for reference:

```
<?php

get_header(); 

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) );

?>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                    the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');
                    the_content();

                endwhile;

                the_posts_pagination();

            else :

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none' );

            endif;

            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

***EDIT AFTER QUESTION ANSWERED***

OK, so it appears that even though I set the 'posts_per_page' that I wanted to display here:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

Wordpress was still relying on the settings in ***Dashboard->Settings->Reading->Blog pages show at most*** to determine pagination, so I had to go in there and set that as well. I still couldn't get the_posts_pagination to work correctly, but this did:

```
previous_posts_link( ' << Newer Entries ' );
next_posts_link( ' Older Entries >> ', $query->max_num_pages);
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180784/what-is-the-difference-between-paged-and-page

Comment: @EdDogan Thanks for the article, that helps me understand the paged vs. page difference. I think I'm using paged correctly though since this is a blog posts index page (home.php), right? If I remove the conditional statement and just get the 'paged' query var, I still get the same result.

Comment: Is the result the same if you use other pagination functions such as `<?php next_posts_link(); ?><?php previous_posts_link(); ?>`

Comment: @EdDogan Yes, I originally tried those because I was following older tutorials but then came upon newer material that said to use the_post_pagination()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_posts_pagination()` does not recognise your new query, but it is reading from the global wp_query stored in `$GLOBALS['wp_query']`.

The **Blog pages show at most** setting under Settings > Reading in the administration panel is the one used as `posts_per_page` here.

You can find some different ways to modify the default query in [this article](http://presscustomizr.com/snippet/three-techniques-to-alter-the-query-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Weird that even though the query that is getting the posts works through the 'posts_per_page' setting in the new WP_Query, I still have to go into settings to get pagination to work. WordPress is strange so far! Thanks for the help!